# pyparsing: Matching comment lines

Tags: pyparsing

I'm building a partial parser for the NATURAL programming language. A comment starts with `"/*"`, `"* "` or `"** "` and ends together with the line. The latter two patterns are used to mark an entire line as comment, so they may be preceded only by whitespace. For the first type,

```
parser.ignore("/* " + SkipTo(lineEnd))
```

works fine. For the second type, I tried

```
parser.ignore(lineStart + Optional(White(" ")) + "* " + SkipTo(lineEnd))
```

which works when `"* "` is at the beginning of the line, but not when it is preceded by spaces.

What am I missing?

Comment: According to the documentation, `Optional(...)` matches zero or one occurrence only.  A line starting with, e.g., `   * foo` has three, not one, blanks before `* `.  The `ZeroOrMore` function allows zero-or-more occurrences of whatever its argument is and would seem more appropriate.

Comment: I think `White(...)` already matches more than one character. The problem seems to be that the parser treats whitespace differently than other character classes. For instance, if I replace `White(" ")` by `Word(".")` and I replace the leading spaces by dots, then then it works.

Comment: `Word` has a one-or-more style action.  Have you actually tried `ZeroOrMore`?  (It does make sense that `White` would be one or more, but I don't know whether it is.)